# How is external (cross-domain) JSON loaded into D3.js using Python/Flask/Jinja?

Tags: javascript, python, json, d3.js, jinja2

[I'm new to all of the languages tagged so be gentle!]

I'm building a little app on Heroku which uses d3.js to display JSON data on a world map.

I want to load json directly to d3.js from a url, but on my local box it's getting blocked by the client

> GET http://earthquake-report.com/feeds/recent-eq?json net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT

and AFAIK loading directly from javascript from another domain is a no-no, and anyway is server-side config which I'm pretty sure I don't have access to in Heroku.

So as a workaround I'm loading it in Python as follows:

```
earthquake_url = "http://earthquake-report.com/feeds/recent-eq?json"
response = urllib2.urlopen(earthquake_url)
json_response = json.load(response)
```

I then pass the json from python to d3.js through jinja parameters:

```
return render_template('main.html', json_response=json.dumps(json_response), **templateData)
```

And on the javascript side the following gets me an object which looks exactly like the json when it's loaded from a local file:

```
var json_response = {{ json_response|safe }}
console.log(json_response)
```

[image]

```
queue()
    .defer(d3.json, "/static/js/readme-world.json")
    .defer(d3.json, "/static/js/earthquake.json")
    .await(ready);

function ready(error, world, data) {
    console.log(data)
```

[image]

What I am asking is:

1. How do I pass my downloaded json data to my 'drawing' function in d3?
2. Why can't I pass my json_response variable to d3.json which returns `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'objects' of undefined`?
3. Why can't I simply load directly from a url into d3?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, it looks like I was being dumb.  I changed this code as follows:

```
queue()
    .defer(d3.json, "/static/js/readme-world.json")
    .defer(d3.json, "/static/js/earthquake.json")
    .await(ready);

function ready(error, world, data) {
    console.log(data)
```

To this:

```
queue()
    .defer(d3.json, "/static/js/readme-world.json")

    .await(ready);

function ready(error, world) {
    console.log(data)
```

And plugged my json_response into my data join code as follows:

```
var g = svg.append("g");

        g.selectAll("circle")
           .data(json_response)
           .enter()
           .append("circle")
```

And it works!

What really helped me was inserting a `debug;` statement after the `queue` to see what state everything was in.  This confirmed that json_response was indeed exactly the same as earthquake.json and encouraged me to check my code for errors again.